# General Strategies for Profiling Simultaneous Asynchronous Requests

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, callback, profiling

We have a system that makes 1 to N asynchronous requests ("foo") within the same time frame.  These are launched on threads other than the main and all of these requests don't necessarily originate from the same thread.

Callbacks for the asynchronous requests are all handled on one specific thread, which for the sake of discussion, we'll call the 'bar' thread.

Everything done 'request side' is opaque to us.  We don't have access to that library.

Up to this point in time, we've gotten away with a very naive profiler which basically calls `markStart('measurement name')` and `markDone('measurement name')` to time a request.  I'm getting closer to having to profile the individual foo requests, from the time we start the foo request, to when it is handled by bar.

Obviously our existing profiler won't work, and I'll need to introduce a way to associate the correct `markDone()` call in callback with its corresponding `markStart()` from a foo.

If our requests had some manner of sequence number returned in response it would be straight forward, however we don't have those.

**Is there a smart, generic way that I can associate an ID with each of the requests, that is visible across threads, or is profiling in this situation usually handled differently (if at all)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any profiler that will be useful for this.
That doesn't mean they don't exist.

I have faced this kind of problem before.
I wrote a book, and discussed this in it.
Basically I came up with two methods, one that works within-thread, and the other across threads.
You really need both, because either one can spend time unnecessarily.

So here are some scanned pages:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mike.  This is awesome.  I've been thinking very 'nuts and bolts' about how to attack the problem, this is a very interesting holistic view.  I'll have some nice problems to think about over the weekend.